# Excel upload, store it into database using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, excel

I'm developing a web application.My App is using Javascript, PHP, HTML. I already done apply code to upload xlsx , attach it on screen .

Here's my Code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="simple-excel.js"></script>
<table width=50% align="left" border=0 STYLE="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:9.2%"><b>Load CSV file</b></td>
            <td style="width:1%"><b>:</b></td> 
            <td style="width:15%"><input type="file" id="fileInputCSV" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 <table id="result"></table>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            // check browser support
            // console.log(SimpleExcel.isSupportedBrowser);

            var fileInputCSV = document.getElementById('fileInputCSV'); 


            // when local file loaded
            fileInputCSV.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

                // parse as CSV
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                var csvParser = new SimpleExcel.Parser.CSV();
                csvParser.setDelimiter(',');
                csvParser.loadFile(file, function () {

                    // draw HTML table based on sheet data
                    var sheet = csvParser.getSheet();
                    var table = document.getElementById('result');
                    table.innerHTML = "";
                    sheet.forEach(function (el, i) {                    
                        var row = document.createElement('tr');
                        el.forEach(function (el, i) {
                            var cell = document.createElement('td');
                            cell.innerHTML = el.value;
                            row.appendChild(cell);
                        });
                        table.appendChild(row);
                    });                    

                });
            });



        </script>
```

How do i supposed to do for add it into database?

Comment: Please refer https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: You should add information about which database ( MySQL,Postgre, etc), and, what does displaying it as a table has to do with saving it to the database?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is for load and parse the file in browser (client-side), if you want to insert the data of a XLSX file into a database like MySQL you need to upload the file to a server-side script (you said you are using PHP) and parse it using a library like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).

You can use this [PHPExcel Cheat Sheet](https://gist.github.com/jrobinsonc/2481d2e6f3d5eb2dffd25b2de20fd593) to know how to parse the file.
If you need help creating the code to upload the file you can visit this link: [PHP 5 File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).